# Rank of matrix with full-rank submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let us consider a matrix $X = [X_1, X_2]$ where both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are of full column rank. When $M_{X_1}X_2 \neq 0$ holds where $$M_{X_1} := I - X_1 (X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'$$ can we say that $X = [X_1, X_2]$ has full column rank? Or are there any counter examples?

Comment: What are the dimensions of these matrices?

Comment: $X_1$ is $n \times p_1$, $X_2$ is $n \times p_2$ and $n>p_1+p_2$.

Comment: No. Consider $X_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$ and $X_2=I_2$ for instance.

Comment: Many thanks for providing a counter example!